# Al poner una imagen PNG esta me sale con fondo

Tags: html, css, imagen

Lo que sucede es que al momento de intentar poner una imagen `png` que he copiado desde internet esta me sale con el fondo y no transparente como se supone que deberia ser.

Acá mi fragmento de código:

```css
#right {
  background: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/206/219/png-transparent-city-structure-icons-industry-industrial-design-factory-petroleum-earth-on-the-factory-cartoon-pattern-infographic-cartoon-character-building-thumbnail.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 28);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="right"></div>
```

Y lo que resulta con la imagen es esto:

[image: esto]

Comment: Esto no es error de HTML ni de CSS, es la imagen, le han puesto ese fondo,

Comment: Esa imagen no tiene el fondo transparente.

Answer (score 4):

Efectivamente esa imagen viene con ese fondo asi, la tienes que editar con un programa de edicion ya sea Photoshop para quitarle ese fondo que simula la transparencia o buscar otra distinta que si sea png. Segundo, recuerda las buenas practicas a la hora de programar y en lo posible, linkea (src) las imagenes desde tu computadora y no de internet, puesto que en este ultimo son susceptibles a cambios en el servidor o la url.